# Why we need lightning in salesforce?

Tags: lightning

Why we need lightning in salesforce ? and What are main advantages over visualforce ? Any prerequites to learn lightning ?

Comment: trailhead has all the details u need : check this module for the different UI options and when to use what .. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/lex_dev/lex_dev_overview/lex_dev_overview_future

Comment: Though this looks to be either too broad or primarily opinion based I'd vote to keep it open as it is a relevant topic.

Answer (score 4):

While this question is pretty general and can be opinion based, I think it is think worthwhile to keep it here as there are many developers (including me previously) are confused about this. It is just like how to learn Visualforce or how to get 501 certified. It is pretty opinion based, but still good to keep.

So below are my two cents about why lightning is better.

1. It uses a stateless framework instead of the stateful one by
       Visualforce. So it will no longer use view state. The benefit of
       this is it will dramatically reduce the transition data between
       client and server.
2. It is a Single Page Application framework which can be considered a today's main framework of websites. It is more responsive and much faster.
3. It forces Javascript to be in a separate file which enforced separation of concern. It is a good habit of writing code.
4. It is fully based on components. And have a full structure of MVC.
5. The look and feel of lightning component is closer to lightning experience. If you are using Visualforce tags in a lightning org, you will find the look and feel a bit strange. Just like having a Windows 98 window on a Windows 7 system.

So gradually, lightning will take place. But there are some reasons why it isn't fully replacing Visualforce now:

1. Lightning experience is still not very mature at this point. If you look at Winter 17's new version, you will notice the lightning exp has changed a lot again. And there are still issues/good reasons to block users moving out of classic.
2. Salesforce is not fully supporting lightning app for now. For example, you can redirect your standard new and edit button into a VF page, but you can't redirect them into a lightning component.